# Directx 11 CreateVertexShader memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, directx, directx-11, vertex-shader

Hi I have a memory leak when creating and releasing vertex shader.

Here is my compiled shader https://pastebin.com/raw/4w8tyY1n

And here is my pretty simple code I just create device and context, then vertex shader and then I all release in a loop.

```
HRESULT hr;

while(true)
{
    ID3D11Device* device;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceCtx;
    ID3D11VertexShader* vertexShader;

    hr = D3D11CreateDevice (
        nullptr,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        nullptr,
        D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT,
        nullptr,
        0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &device,
        nullptr,
        &deviceCtx);

    if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
    {
        UINT Size = ARRAYSIZE (g_VS);
        hr = device->CreateVertexShader (g_VS, Size, nullptr, &vertexShader);
        if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
        {
            vertexShader->Release ();
        }

        deviceCtx->Release ();
        device->Release ();
    }
}
```

I'm stuck with this i have read every possible msdn documentation on this and I just don't know what might be the problem.

Comment: What makes you think you have a memory leak? What metric do you check? Do you understand that "while(true)" loop has side effects that might look like a memory leak but be not a memory leak exactly? The code runs fine for me.

Comment: Hi I found out that when I'm running the code the memory goes up to 450 MB and then the app crashes on line 

hr = device->CreateVertexShader (g_VS, Size, nullptr, &vertexShader);

with 
Exception thrown at 0x771D5D15 (ntdll.dll) in D3D11.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008. occurred

When I comment CreateVertexShader line there is no problem and I'm consistently bellow 20 megabytes.

Comment: Ok So I find out that it only happens on intel GPU it seems it might to be the same problem as here https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D70P0000068e6USAQ/directx11-memory-leak-on-win10-with-intel-hd530?language=en_US

Comment: When using C++, you shouldn't rely on manual ``AddRef``` / ``Release`` calls for COM objects as it's too easy to miss one. Just use [ComPtr](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the problem was with Intel® HD Graphics 620 drivers an update fix everything for me.